# Apply different class to list item in v-for dynamically created items vuejs

Tags: vue.js

All I want to do is apply a conditional class to a list item as it is pushed to my `messages` array and then shown on screen. However, I do not want the all of the previous list items to have the same styling applied. Every time a new item is added, it checks what class should be applied, depending on whether sender or receiver of message, and then it applies whichever class necessary to all list items, but I only want it to be applied that new item. How can I achieve this?

app.js:

```
const chatWindow = new Vue({
    el: '#chatWindow',
    data: {
        messages: [],
        currentUser: document.getElementById('sender').value,
        sender: true
    },
    methods: {
        sendMessage: function () {
            this.$http.post('/chat', {message: this.message, sender: this.currentUser}).then((response) => {
                console.log('request sent successfully');
            }, (response) => {
                console.log('request not sent');
            });

            this.message = '';
        }
    },
    props: ['message']
});

window.Echo.channel('test-chat-channel')
    .listen('MessageSent', (event) => {
        chatWindow.$data.sender = event.sender == chatWindow.$data.currentUser;
        chatWindow.$data.messages.push(event);
    });
```

chat.blade.php (view):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="border: 2px solid black; height: 500px;">
                <h2 class="text-center no-top">Sidebar</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="chatWindow" class="col-sm-7">
                <h1 class="text-center no-top">Chat</h1>
                <div class="chat-window">
                    <input type="hidden" id="sender" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    <ul id="chat-messages">
                        <li v-for="message in messages" :class="sender ? 'left' : 'right'">
                            @{{ message.message }}
                            <span class="pull-right">@{{ message.timestamp }}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input title="Send Message" v-model="message" @keyup.enter="sendMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Send message...">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs" style="border: 2px solid black; height: 500px;">
                <h2 class="text-center no-top">Infobar</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
@endsection
```

Comment: maybe have two values one for messages :[] and one for  newMessages : []?

Comment: Won't this cause the same problem though? As soon  as New message is placed into the old messages, the old messages will all take the same class as the most recent?

Comment: my thought would be to have one <li v-for="messages"> and one <li v-for="new_messages">

Comment: How would this prevent overwriting existing styles? Why does this even happen? It's ridiculous that Vue that is modifying exist elements without explicit instruction to do so, and no clear method of preventing it from doing so

Comment: Just add the style data as a property on your message when you push it and bind that property to the class or style of the element in the loop

Comment: Yes that is a good approach